# C FIFO crashes when writer goes faster than reader

Tags: c, pipe, fifo

I have a parent and child process using fork who communicate using a FIFO pipe. The program will sometimes work and other times it will crash when the writer process (parent) goes faster than the reader process (child).

The following code is what I currently have.

```
void writeprocess(char* text);
void readprocess(void);

#define FIFO_NAME     "MYTESTFIFO"
#define MAX         200

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid==0){
        printf("Started child process.\n");
        mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666);
        readprocess();
        printf("Child process finished.\n");
         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else{
        printf("Started parent process.\n");
        mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666);

        writeprocess("Message 1");
        writeprocess("Message 2");
        writeprocess("Message 3");
        writeprocess("Message 4");
        writeprocess("terminate");

        printf("Waiting for child process to finish.\n");
        int returnStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &returnStatus, 0);
        printf("Parent process also finished.\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

void writeprocess(char* text){
    FILE *fp;
    char *send_buf;

    fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "w");
    asprintf( &send_buf, "%s\n", text);
    if ( fputs( send_buf, fp ) == EOF )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error writing data to fifo\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    printf("Message send: %s", send_buf);
    free( send_buf );

    fclose(fp);
}

void readprocess(){
    sleep(1);
    FILE *fp;
    char *str_result = NULL;
    char recv_buf[MAX];

    int stringdifference = 1;

    while (stringdifference)
    {
        fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "r");
        str_result = fgets(recv_buf, MAX, fp);
        if ( str_result != NULL )
        {
            printf("Message received: %s", recv_buf);
        }
        fclose( fp );

        stringdifference = strncmp(str_result, "terminate", 9);
    }
}
```

When the writer writes faster to the FIFO pipe than the reader can read, I get an exit error with the following message: "Terminated due to signal 13". How can I avoid this from happening while keeping my program run at full performance?

I do want the parent process to be able to end the process and I have to keep working using a FIFO pipe.

Comment: Why do your reader/writer processes repeatedly open and close the pipe? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: You never check for errors — you've no idea when the code starts going wrong.

Comment: When both ends of a FIFO are closed, any data unread in the pipe is discarded.  You probably need to revise the code so as to hold the FIFO open much longer than you currently do.

Comment: @melpomene, this is a basic implementation. My real program runs three threads that all write to the same fifo, that's why I need to close it for writing.

Comment: Of course it "crashes".  `fopen` fails, but you aren't checking that.  Instead, you just assume it returned a valid file pointer and tried to write to it.

Comment: @suchmitch That makes no sense.

Comment: Just because 3 threads are all writing to the same fifo doesn't mean you need to open and close it each time you send data.  Open it once.  Spawn threads.  Have each thread write data.  When they're done writing, close it.  Or, have each thread open the file once, write data until they're done, and then close.  But that's harder to implement if you use a named fifo.  It would be much easier to use a pipe.

Comment: The file stream functions are required to be thread-safe — the three threads can share the same file stream as long as the message is written with a single I/O function — or you can use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` if need so be.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Or just use `write()`, as write operations less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes will be atomic.  There's no guarantee that `fputs()` will write the string with a single `write()` operation, so there no guarantee that `fgets()` on the read end will get a complete string as passed to `fputs()`.

Comment: Is this some kind of school assignment? It rarely makes sense to use a FIFO for parent/child comms. Normally you would use an unnamed pipe.

Comment: @n.m. it indeed is a school assignment for which it's obligatory to use FIFO in combination with fork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the writer writes faster to the FIFO pipe than the reader can read, I get an exit error with the following message: "Terminated due to signal 13".

You have mischaracterized the nature of the problem.  As your other answer already observes, signal 13 is `SIGPIPE`, which is delivered if you try to write to a pipe that has no readers.

There is normally some (limited) protection against entering that situation with FIFOs, in that opening one end of a FIFO blocks until the other end is opened as well. Therefore if a process opens a FIFO successfully, it knows that there is initially another process with the other end open.  The one with the write end open can then expect a high likelihood of writing successfully (but not necessarily without blocking).  As soon as the last reader closes the FIFO, however, further attempts to write to it will cause a `SIGPIPE` to be delivered to the writer.  Of course, if the same or a new reader opens the FIFO, that permits writing to resume -- something that's possible with a FIFO, but not with an ordinary pipe.

So the problem is not that the reader does not keep up, but rather that it keeps opening and closing the FIFO.  This creates a race condition, in that there are multiple intervals in which the writer will elicit a `SIGPIPE` if it tries to write.  Since the writer *also* repeatedly opens and closes the FIFO, it follows that to receive a `SIGPIPE`, the writer must reopen the FIFO before the reader closes it after a previous message, but that doesn't mean the writer is outpacing the reader.  The reader cannot finish reading a given message before the writer finishes writing it, so their behaviors are staggered.  The writer does nothing else between closing the FIFO and reopening it, so it is not surprising that it sometimes reopens before the reader closes.

The solution is simple: have each process keep the pipe open continuously until it is done communicating with the other.  There is no upside to opening and closing for each message, but plenty of downside.  For your particular use, however, it may be beneficial to put the writer's stream in line-buffered mode ([`setvbuf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf); default will be fully-buffered).

Answer (score 1):

Signal 13 is SIGPIPE. This happens because nobody is reading from the FIFO.

You cannot write to a FIFO if there is no process that currently has that FIFO open for reading. If you try to do this, your process will get SIGPIPE (which can be ignored, which turns it into EPIPE... but either way, it fails).

One way to handle this correctly:

1. Create the FIFO in the parent.
2. Fork.

   - In the writer process, open it for writing. This will block until the reader has opened it. Keep it open.
   - In the reader process, open it for writing. This will block until the writer has opened it. Keep it open.

Comment: If you 'open the FIFO for reading' before forking, the `open()` will block until there's a writer (and there won't be a writer, so the program will stop).  If the program creates the FIFO, forks, opens the FIFO (for reading, for writing), does the reading/writing, closes the FIFO — that's a more plausible sequence.